# Node.js: PDFkit write to response

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation

I'm using PDFKit (A PDF generation library for Node.js, [pdfkit.org](http://pdfkit.org)) and I want to send a PDF as a response to a client.

```
# Write the PDF file to disk
doc.write('output.pdf');
```

The code above writes the PDF file to the disk, but I want it to send as the response. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `res` is your server response object, just do this:

```
doc.output(function(string) {
  res.end(string);
});
```

This will send a string representation of the PDF rather than writing it to file. The code above is the compiled CoffeeScript that was in the documentation for PDFKit.

```
doc.output (string) -> 
  console.log string
```

Comment: Remember to set binary mode: `res.end(string,'binary')` otherwise the PDF output will be corrupted.

Comment: fyi this method has been deprecated.